# How to improve image quality in Android Webkit (comparing with iOS)

Tags: android, html, ios, css, webkit

Trying to load http://www.sciences-physiques.eu/appli/oneimage/ both in iOS and Android (SGS2).

Image is 1600*2262

The result is a better image on iOS. I know android can do better, because I had an application with such big image downsized, and the text was "clearer".

I red a lot about adding some code in css, but it seems that it does not apply to webkit

Here are the screenshots :

http://tof.canardpc.com/show/9144d047-0aaf-4906-9c96-1a991112f9fc.html
http://tof.canardpc.com/show/36008198-e6ef-4b02-820b-fe2ca8b8df1c.html

The code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>carimage</title>
    <style type="text/css">
         img { width: 100%; }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #1985D0
        }
        </style>
        <body>

<img src="1.png" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just that you know, if I put max-width instead of width, the result is worse than with only the "width" attribute.

Comment: I just have to ask.... Does it really make *that* much of a difference to your users? We're talking pixels here yea?

Comment: Yes Phix. Because I'll have physics, chemistry, math and for good rendering I use Latek. So I have to use image. On Android my pupils say I could use something better than a bad scanner. On iOS they say it's like in their books...

Comment: Ok, so then instead of having an image 4x larger than the screen, why not use some server side magic to resize it down, and thus circumventing this issue?

Comment: 1. It's not 4x. Retinas are 1536*xxxx.
2. I'll build an apk, so there will be no server. 
Again, when builded native, the image is fine. Using webkit goes to an awful image on Android.

Comment: I'm confused now. Why are you building this apk with this monstrous image included, to then show it in a browser on the device? I'd really like to help, but it seems like this is a design issue more than a css one.

Comment: Lol. Like I said it's not so monstrous. Look at the spec of Iphone and Ipad. It's more like testing. When I build the apk und running it, the phone is using webkit, I'll have the same rendering image, like on iOS.

Answer (score -1):

The quality of images in iOS apps are better than those of android (having same resolution), image quality gets improved with the specified code but the time for loading increases. While doing android application development for my client I implemented the code and felt the difference in both quality and loading time.

Comment: Did you forget your code or are you just spamming your website?